# Heroku Idling because quota is exhausted

Tags: heroku

What does this mean? State changed from up to down Idling because quota is exhausted Stopping all processes with SIGTERM

My heroku app shut down and when I type heroku logs -t it give me this

```
 State changed from crashed to starting
2019-02-27T09:41:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-02-27T09:41:57.263955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 41036 -e production`
2019-02-27T09:42:08.039524+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-27T09:42:08.050315+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2019-02-27T09:42:08.054726+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2019-02-27T09:42:08.066260+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling because quota is exhausted
2019-02-27T09:42:07.658395+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-27 09:42:07] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2019-02-27T09:42:07.658431+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-27 09:42:07] INFO  ruby 2.3.7 (2018-03-28) [x86_64-linux]
2019-02-27T09:42:07.658737+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-27 09:42:07] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4 port=41036
2019-02-27T09:42:08.831687+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H82 desc="Free app running time quota exhausted" method=GET path="/" host=www.petraauto.com request_id=17318012-510b-47e2-9277-fe1a448ec3ea fwd="174.6.158.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-02-27T09:42:09.238077+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270539+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-27 09:42:09] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270590+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:177:in `select'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270592+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:177:in `block in start'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270594+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:33:in `start'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270596+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:164:in `start'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270597+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270599+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270600+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270605+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270606+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270608+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270610+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270611+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270613+00:00 app[web.1]: bin/rails:4:in `require'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.270615+00:00 app[web.1]: bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2019-02-27T09:42:09.273222+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-27 09:42:09] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2019-02-27T09:42:09.273252+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-27 09:42:09] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2019-02-27T09:42:09.273368+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've run out of time on your Free Dynos.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h82-free-dyno-quota-exhausted
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#free-dyno-hour-pool

Comment: I added my credit card to have free dyno this morning but the app still pausing!

Comment: The account verification allocates additional Free Dyno hours, however Free Dynos still sleep: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping

Comment: They activate it at first of the month

Answer (score 0):

### **RECENT UPDATE

Hey your post helped me out this morning. Unfortunately, minutes later, I received an email from Salesforce.
It looks like moving forward Heroku will no longer offer the free services, such as free Dynos. I think it discontinues November 28th or so.
Give the following a read: https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter
And prepare accordingly for your applications using free dynos!